# querydsl JPAAnnotationProcessor generate from dependecy

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

i have multi module maven project, that have a module for spring jpa repositories, and a module of domain entities. domain module is dependency of repositories module.
the apt-maven-plugin is on the repositories module. i want to JPAAnnotationProcessor scan entities in domain module and generate Q classes in repositories module.

how can i configure this?

Comment: I think simple placing the plug-in inside the pom in your Domain module would do the trick

Comment: if the plug-in is in the domain module, plugin doing generate in domain module, but i want it generate classes into repositories. because QClasses is related to repositories not the domains.

Comment: I think `JPAAnnotationProcessor`  scans classes with `@entity` annotation only.

Comment: yes , but it scans only classes in the current project classpath. not other modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

The JPAAnnotationProcessor is an APT plugin for Maven.
APT stands for Annotation Processing Tool, which is executed at *compile-time*. More precisely it wraps the compiler in order to generate more sources that will also be compiled afterwards.
See also http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17876.html

This means that the Querydsl APT Maven plugin must be configured in the modules where the *sources* reside that have to be processed.

But this is typically what you want.
The Q-classes are meta-models, i.e. they describe your domain models and therefore belong to them.
Your repositories operate on them as well as the do with the entities (meta-models to describe the query, entities are returned by repositories).